# Slow plotting of spatial data in macOS RStudio's plotting device

Tags: r, sp, plot

In my macOS system RStudio, plotting spatial data (statialpolygons, points and lines) is extremely slow, making it impossible to work with.

When I try to plot the shapefile in this link (@https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0XRH7FN95-RSzFRckhXNjVWYlk), it takes about 30 minutes in RStudio.
If I plot in R (outside RStudio), it takes about 20 minutes to print in an external plotting windows titled Quartz2. On the contrary, it is a couple of less than a minute in a window's machine in my lab with equivalent specs.

The best workaround I know is to use a pdf as plotting device (or png). Doing that, it takes just a couple of seconds.

```
shp <- readOGR("~/stof_shp", "AP_PAT_edited1")
pdf()
plot(shp)
dev.off()
```

But it is not a satisfactory solution. I love work with spatial data on R, but the biggest inconvenient is the difficulty for visualizing the data, and this makes it much harder.

I have talked with different people that are in my same situation, but there doesn't seem to be too much information about it when you google or search in gis.stackexchange. I have doubts on whether it affects all macOS systems, or only laptops, only some version of the OS or all of them. My system and applications are updated.

> sessionInfo()
>       R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>       Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0 (64-bit)
>       Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

At some point, I thought it was the matter of my version of `gdal` or `proj`, but I am confident now that I have the latests set and working. I have `rgdal_1.2-8` and `sp_1.2-5`.

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.2-8, (SVN revision 663)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
 Path to GDAL shared files: /opt/local/share/gdal
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5
```

I have also been messing with XQuartz and X11, getting nowhere (I wouldn't know how to get the info of which versions I have installed, but if I enter `X11()` on RStudio, it will try to start X11, but it will crash in an infinite loop that I have been unable to fix).

I started the question in stackoverflow, but I was told to post the question here, where it belongs better. Few months ago I made similar question here, but I did not reproduce the example data and I think that I might have been missleading in how I presented the problem (@[Slow plotting SpatialPolygonDataFrames on some systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238136/slow-plotting-spatialpolygondataframes-on-some-systems)). For those reasons I am starting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, I also think that using RStudio for plotting is slower than only using R. I suggest you try using `sf` package because it's faster for loading spatial vector data than `rgdal` see here: [Simple Features for R](https://edzer.github.io/sfr/articles/sfr.html) and [First Impressions From sf – The Simple Features R Package](https://geographicdatascience.com/2017/01/06/first-impressions-from-sf-the-simple-features-r-package/). Also, I had a better impression for performance when plotting than `sp`. And `sf` will replace `sp`.

I tried download your shapefile and plot in RStudio using `sf`. It took some seconds to make the visualizations.

```
# Load libraries
library('sf') # manage spatial vector data
library('mapview') # interactive map visualization in R

# Load data from ESRI shapefile
AP_PAT_edited1 <- st_read("AP_PAT_edited1.shp")

# View data 
head(AP_PAT_edited1)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -70.21592 ymin: 7.712805 xmax: -66.27898 ymax: 12.04268
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
  id                       geometry
1  1 MULTIPOLYGON(((-69.96232793...
2  1 MULTIPOLYGON(((-67.01927266...
3  1 MULTIPOLYGON(((-69.84210651...
4 10 MULTIPOLYGON(((-67.59778541...
5 10 MULTIPOLYGON(((-70.08384200...
6 11 MULTIPOLYGON(((-66.28849953...    

# Simple plot shapefile
plot(AP_PAT_edited1, 
     xlab = "Longitude", 
     ylab = "Latitude",
     graticule = st_crs(4326), 
     axes = TRUE, main = "Plot")
```

[image: simplePlot]

```
# Interactive plot with mapview
mapView(AP_PAT_edited1, zcol = 'id')
```

[image: interactivePlot]

Comment: thanks for your detailed comment. I knew sf, but had never given it a try. It was surprisingly nice to test it, but when it comes to plotting, I am stuck with the same problem. It also takes ages using RStudio's device. However, it made me more confidence into thinking that it is the device's problem.

Comment: @JavierFajardo what a pity, I had the hope that maybe changing libraries would solve the problem. Using `mapview` is also slow? That seems to be some graphic card related problem.

Comment: @JavierFajardo did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is a recurrent issue. Trying to export it as pdf is way faster that doing it in jpeg or other graphical formats. In base R, the function does take a little less, but only exporting as pdf makes it really really fast.

I am also using macOS but on a super-charged MacBook Pro M1 Max with 64GB of RAM, so muscle power shouldn't be the reason behind this. Im on R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid", RStudio is on the latest.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252998)